# Return boolean if one element matches among 2 arrays in postgresql

Tags: sql, database, postgresql

I have 2 `arrays` in postgresql and I need to return true if there are at least 1 match of element between these 2 arrays no mather if it is same position.

Follows example below:

```
select array(select generate_series(0,10)) = 
       any(select array(select generate_series(10,11)))
```

it should return `true` because I have 10 in both arrays

Answer (score 2, accepted):

https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/functions-array.html

> `=`   equal
>
> `&&`  overlap (have elements in common)

formatting mine. You need other operator

```
select array(select generate_series(0,10)) &&
       any(select array(select generate_series(10,11)));
 ?column?
----------
 t
(1 row)
```

Answer (score 1):

Go for && operator

like

```
SELECT ARRAY['apple','cherry','avocado'] && ARRAY['applea','cherrya','avocado']

SELECT ARRAY[1,4,3] && ARRAY[2,1]
```

https://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.6/static/functions-array.html